# SQLServer 2008 arithmetic overflow error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to save a large number with decimals in sql table but so far no luck.

The data type of my column is numeric(25, 20), but when I try to enter data it is giving the following error.

[image: Screen shot of error message]

I have really large numbers with around 18 decimal places.

Am I using the correct data type for the column? or can you suggest me a method to overcome this issue?

Comment: What is the command executed?

Comment: `insert` command

Comment: Can you show the query + source and destination table structure

Comment: The problem is almost certainly to do with the actual value you are using. Have you tested the query with small values?

Comment: I have found the solution, The problem was that i tried to enter numbers with more than 5 digits before the decimal, so I increased the precision to `numeric(30,20)` and it works.